# Given two sparse vectors, compute their dot product

Tags: java, array, hash-map, mapreduce

Problem Statement:

Given two sparse vectors, compute their dot product.

Implement class SparseVector:

SparseVector(nums) Initializes the object with the vector nums
dotProduct(vec) Compute the dot product between the instance of SparseVector and vec
A sparse vector is a vector that has mostly zero values, you should store the sparse vector efficiently and compute the dot product between two SparseVector.

Questions:
I have written the following code using Hashmap to calculate the dot product for sparse vectors. Compared to using an array, this method seems faster. But I want to get some opinions on hashmap solution in terms of scalability. My point is that if my nums array is very large (billions), I can get hash collisions and my hash bucket's linkedlist may become longer. Plus, I may have to resize my hashmap periodically while traversing the nums array. Also, in real-life, my memory tends to be limited, which may worsens the runtime complexity of hashmap approach. Comparing to the array approach, I feel that we can simply use map-reduce or parallel programming to calculate the dot product. Therefore, I feel the array based approach may be better in terms of scalability. Please give me some pointers about it.

## HashMap Method

```
class SparseVector {
    
    
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> sparseVec;
    
    SparseVector(int[] nums) {
        sparseVec = new HashMap<>();
        
        for(int i =0;i<nums.length;i++){
            if(nums[i] > 0){
                sparseVec.put(i, nums[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Return the dotProduct of two sparse vectors
    public int dotProduct(SparseVector vec) {
        
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> othvec = vec.sparseVec;
        
        // get the keyList of that sparseVec
        List<Integer> othKeyList = new ArrayList<>(othvec.keySet());
        
        int dotProduct = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<othKeyList.size();i++){
            int nonZeroIndex = othKeyList.get(i);
            if(this.sparseVec.containsKey(nonZeroIndex)){
                dotProduct += (this.sparseVec.get(nonZeroIndex) *
                              othvec.get(nonZeroIndex));
            }
        }
        
        return dotProduct;
        
    }
}

// Your SparseVector object will be instantiated and called as such:
// SparseVector v1 = new SparseVector(nums1);
// SparseVector v2 = new SparseVector(nums2);
// int ans = v1.dotProduct(v2);
```

## Array method

```
class SparseVector {

    private int[] array;

    SparseVector(int[] nums) {
        array = nums;
    }

    public int dotProduct(SparseVector vec) {
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            result += array[i] * vec.array[i];
        }
        return result;
    }   
}
```

Comment: A hash map is not the right way to store a sparse vector. Use an array of (index, value) pairs, the array is sorted by index. This is much more efficient for computation. The dictionary is more efficient when modifying the array, but you don’t modify any arrays.

Comment: Also, a plain array is possibly faster, depending on the number of zero entries. The big advantage of sparse representation is the reduced memory use.

Comment: @CrisLuengo If the array is sufficiently sparse, and access is random enough, the theoretically constant-time access would have a lot of page faults. These might be slower than a binary search of a compressed sparse representation that fits into cache.

Comment: @Davislor I guess I’m biased, thinking of linear algebra, where there’s no random access ever.